# Why Docker official images are using an Operating System

Tags: docker, container

Docker containers does not need an operating system and a hypervisor because they use the host kernel. So why all of the official images like: php, nginx, .. whatever are using an operating system in their images:

Example: PHP 7 official image (from Docker Hub) is using Debian:

```
FROM debian:jessie
```

App containers are not VMs and provide process isolation, not OS isolation.

Am I missing something important in my understanding ?

Answer (score 2):

An operating system is more than a kernel; it's a kernel PLUS a tonne of files in userspace.  So things like the files in `/bin` and `/etc` and `/usr/bin` and `/lib`

When you run a container your program typically requires supporting code (shared libraries, scripts) to run.

This isn't always required.  eg if you use `go` to write your program than you can have nothing except the single file

```
$ cat hello.go
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
  fmt.Println("Hello, World")
}
$ go build hello.go
$ strip hello
```

Now your dockerfile can be

```
FROM scratch
COPY hello /
CMD ["/hello"]
```

Trivial case; it's just an example.

But if you try to run `php` then do you know all of the dependencies?  Sometimes it's easier to bring in a minimal copy of a common OS.  But this does have some security risks.

(see also https://www.sweharris.org/post/2016-06-04-small-container/ )

Comment: Good answer. Beware that if you go down the route of using a lot statically linked binaries (I presume that's what `go` does here; it's easy enough with C/C++ too, and probably one way or another with various other languages) you will end up wasting much more RAM than you would have if you'd used a normal operating system based around shared libraries.

Comment: Running static binaries is a major security risk, or at least a major security nightmare: you have to recompile and deploy the binaries every time a flaw is fixed in one of the statically-linked libraries. Relying on a distribution for the libraries is a lot better for security, because the distribution pushes the updates to your doorstep.

Comment: @Giles In a container world you have to be more proactive with patching, anyway, because you shouldn't be patching in place.  https://www.sweharris.org/post/2016-04-10-keeping-safe/  At this point "patching" should become part of your CI/CD workflow and so static vs dynamic becomes less relevant; in both cases track your dependencies and only deploy what you need.